# Nextcloud Docker writing Contents to the SD Card **and** the external drive

Tags: docker, docker-compose, raspberry-pi4, nextcloud

I've installed Nextcloud in a Docker Container on my Raspberry Pi 4 and it's working so far.
As media storage I'm using an external drive which I attached to the container using a volume. In nextcloud I activated the external drive support and added the volume from earlier.

When I upload files to my Nextcloud, I can see that the files are being written to the SD Card **and** the external drive and that's obviously not how it's intended to be.

I can imagine I just forgot something since I am new to Docker and Linux in general so don't judge me :)

Hope you can help me.

That's my docker-compose file:

```
services:

    nextcloud-db:
        image: "mariadb"
        container_name: "nextcloud-db"
        volumes:
            - "NCMariaDB:/var/lib/docker/volumes"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=***
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=***
            - MYSQL_USER=***
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=***
        restart: always
    nextcloud:
        image: "nextcloud"
        container_name: nextcloud
        restart: always
        ports:
        - 8080:80
        volumes: 
            - "/media/elementshdd/nextcloud:/media/nextcloud"
        depends_on:
            - "nextcloud-db"

volumes:
    NCMariaDB:

Edit:
The files are being stored (temporarily) on the SD Card while uploading, and after they're being copied to the external drive automatically. But it seems like they aren't being deleted from the SD Card after copying since the free storage doesn't increase.
```

Comment: How does your Dockerfile or docker-compose look like? Maybe it has something to do with the Volume mapping you use.

Comment: Those are the volume parts of my docker-compose file: 
        volumes:                                       
            - "/media/elementshdd/nextcloud:/media/nextcloud
volumes:                                               
    NCMariaDB:                                         
    NCData:

Comment: This is not enough info. Why not putting the fill docker-compose.yml file in the question?

Comment: I added the docker-compose file now.

Comment: Your nextcloud-db service is just a MySQL database-container. But you have the volume mapping pointing to /var/lib/docker/volumes in (!!) the container. If you want the MySQL database on NCMariaDB on the host, then you should change that to /var/lib/mysql. In Docker-Volumes mapping the left-side of the ':' is on the Host and the right side of the ':' is in the Container itself.

Comment: Oh okay, gonna change that. But how does that matter since I added the nextcloud volume as external storage in the web interface?

Comment: Don't know if that fixes the original problem. But Nextcloud is a commercial product, so I can't test it out.